# Emacs 23, semantic-something-to-tag-table and eassist mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, cedet, emacs-semantic

The very helpful eassist mode relies on CEDET's `semantic-something-to-tag-table` function. Can anyone advice, how this function could be loaded from Emacs' built-in CEDET?

Comment: Are you installed `eassist` manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this function is in `semantic/util` package, that you can load with

```
(require 'semantic/util)
```

command...

P.S. CEDET in Emacs has slightly different directory structure, comparing with current `trunk`

P.P.S. But I would recommend to use CEDET from bzr repo - many things were fixed and improved there

Comment: Thanks for answering, Alex. I've tried that, no luck :( And loading the semantic-util.elc didn't seem an elegant way either. I'll definitely start using the recent version from the repository.

Comment: that's very strange that it doesn't load, although I hadn't checked Emacs 23, only with Emacs 24 (current snapshot) - this library was available if I execute `M-x find-library semantic/util`. You can also check presence of file `lisp/cedet/semantic/util.*` in the emacs's `site-lisp` directory...